# Пробелы и табуляция

Tags: php, form

Здравствуйте! Хочу защитить форму ввода от невидимых символов на стороне сервера средствами PHP(пробел, табуляция). Т.е. когда пользователь вводит ТОЛЬКО пробелы или/и табуляцию то форма у меня отправляется и пустое значение записывается в базу. Как сделать чтобы такого не происходило?

Comment: Количество символов, отображаемых как пробел, слишком велико (как не-пробел - ещё больше). Со всеми бороться - рук не хватит. Так что первичная валидация (на основные пробельные символы) на клиенте - и основная на сервере. И тогда по идее отправка криво заполненной формы тебя не должна особо волновать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается есть простое решение в самом php. `ctype_space`

> Возвращает TRUE, если каждый символ в строке text создает какой-нибудь
>   из пробельных символов, FALSE в противном случае. Кроме пробела, сюда
>   также относятся символы табуляции, вертикальной табуляции, перевода
>   строки, возврата каретки и перевода страницы.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ctype-space.php

```
if (ctype_space($content)) {               
    $content = null;
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
} else {
    $content = htmlspecialchars($content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я могу предложить вариант на стороне клиента - у input'ов задавай атрибут pattern. Туда положи регулярное выражение, в котором будет отслеживаться, находится ли в value ТОЛЬКО пробелы или табуляция. И таким же способом можно дополнительно проверять value на стороне клиента. По моему это решение. Pattern кстати не даст отправить сообщение, которое не проходит валидацию по заданному регулярному выражению.

Comment: А пользователь сам может изменить атрибут pattern? Это ему доступно?

Comment: Ну если прямо в браузере то в принципе да, но как раз для этого будет вторая проверка на стороне сервера. Там то точно не поменяет.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в конкретном типе поля, может быть конкретный тип информации. Валидируйте это просто перед отправкой/вставкой

Например так можно проверить имя пользователя. Состоит из английских букв и цифр, длинной минимум 2, максимум 20 символов

```
//Убрать ведущие и закрывающие пустые символы
$username = trim($username);

if (empty($username) || !preg_match("/^[a-z\d_]{2,20}$/i", $username)){
   echo "Что-то не так";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно регулярным выражением в php вырезать из поля все пробелы и табуляции, и после проверить длину символов поля, если длина после выреза пробелов и табов будет равна 0 - значит поле состояло только из пробелов и табов.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

if( strlen($name) === 0 )
    die('Пустое поле');

// Вырезаем пробелы и табы
$name = preg_replace('/\s\t/', '', $name);

if( strlen($name) === 0 )
    die('Длина поля равна 0, значит были только табы и пробелы');
```